# Run two apache (httpd) servers on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, socket, apache2, multiple-instances

I'm actually working on an old CentOS 6.5 server during my internship in a society that produces maps.

I worked last month on a CRM implementation that runs on an apache2 located in /usr/local/apache2/ and uses some ports.

My boss recently asked me to build a tiles server on the same machine, so
I used a fresh apache2 installation to do it that runs in /etc/httpd (where it's normally suppose to be).

Now, I would like to run all my work at the same time.

In fact, if my old/primary apache2 is already started when I try to start the second one I get:

> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>
> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>
> no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> Unable to open logs

That is quite normal I guess...

I would like to be able to get an access to my tiles with some ports on my second apache2, something like:

> *myserveradress*:*someport*/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

and be able to have an access to the ports 80, 8080 and some others on the first one...

Does someone have ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this is to use [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/).

Comment: Got it, I edited my httpd.conf and chose an other listening port. Thanks !